# Change span's text value when an input radio is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the text 'Rate! (62)' in the 'rate' class to change to 'Rate! (63)' when a user clicks one of the input radios.

The difficulty is that I have many 'stars' divs so this change must occur only to the next span descendant of the enclosing 'stars' div.

```
   <div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5"><label for="star5"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4"><label for="star4"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3"><label for="star3"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2"><label for="star2"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1"><label for="star1"></label>
    </p>
    <span class="rate">Rate! (62)</span>
</div>
```

I'm new to jQuery and this is what I came up with until now but it's not working. i think I have confuse a couple of things on the way:

```
('.rating input:radio').click(function() {
    var str_rate = $(obj).closest('span').next().find('.rate');
    //TODO: parse the current value and add 1 to it
    $(str_rate).html(str);
}
```

Is there something I'm completely missing?

**UPDATE:**
[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLqkh28u/4/) shows the progress until now considering the answers but still it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your selector to find the `span`, change it to:

```
$(obj).parents('.stars').find('.rate');
```

So we get the parent `stars` element, then we get the associated `.rate` `span`.

**ALSO: You're missing a `$` from the start of your `click` function. and `);` from the end of it.**

Comment: getting undefined function: ('.rating input:radio').click(function() {
 $(obj).parents('.stars').find('.rate').html("Thank you");
}

Comment: @Tom You're missing a `$` off the start of your `function` and `);` from the end of it

Comment: I tried using this method but it doesn't work so I tried the answer below in this jsfiddle but it also doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/wLqkh28u/

Comment: @Tom It seems there were a couple of other issues with your code. Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgvto6k1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get change the rate as follows:

```
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1,rate_string.indexOf(")")),10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! " + rate);
```

But note I had a problem with your selector, and had to modify it to get the span area.

Tom
Here's all of the code changes I made:

```
<div class="stars float-left">
<div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5"><label for="star5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4"><label for="star4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3"><label for="star3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2"><label for="star2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1"><label for="star1"></label>
</p>
<span class="rate">Rate! (62)</span>
```

With the following script

```
    $('input:radio').click(function (obj) {
    var str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1,rate_string.indexOf(")")),10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");
});
```

I don't think I changed the html, other than formatting.

Comment: Just realized what the error was with the selector - you should be using $(this), unless you have an additional statement which assigns this to obj.  The selector would be: var str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');

Comment: Tom - let me give you my entire answer as a separate answer - I think there were a couple of other issues with the selector $('.rating input:radio').click(function (... the radio input's don't have a class name radio (just a name).

Comment: Tom - I just re-edited the previous answer - let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score -1):

If your selector is correct ( the str_rate ) then you can probably get the value through var value = str_rate.val() ( see http://api.jquery.com/val/ ). Then you can upp that value and re-set it to the element through the .val() method again, only this time, passing in the new value, or through .html() as you are already using.